# Customer Download Access Management

Tags: cloud-service, server

I represent a software development company.  I have a list of customers.  These customer have purchased one or more of our software-based products.

I am looking for a piece of server software (or a cloud service) which would allow customers to log in to a 'Customer Download' portal, enter their credentials (provided by us, at the time of the first sale), and be presented with download links for whichever products they have purchased, according to our sales database.

Ideally someone from our sales team would be able to log into the management portal to update customer information, grant access to product downloads, etc.

Finding the proper search terms to find such a solution is remarkably challenging.  Is there an existing solution for "Customer Download Management?"

Additional nice-to-haves:

- The customer download portal is custom-branded for our company.
- When a new version of a product is released, customers should have access to this new version *only if* they have an active support agreement.

Comment: Are you looking for free or willing to paid for it?

Comment: Willing to pay.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WHMCS](https://www.whmcs.com/).

Although it is primarily for selling hosting packages, it can be [configured to support product download](http://docs.whmcs.com/Product_Downloads_Distribution).

It is a software so you will have to purchase and install it. There are also hosting company that will provide it as a hosted solution.

With it, you will have the whole customer portal to configure the product and [manage customers](http://docs.whmcs.com/Client_Management). It also can act as a shopping cart for customer to buy your software and also do [invoicing](http://docs.whmcs.com/Invoicing).

In addition, it has a [support ticket](http://docs.whmcs.com/Support_Tickets) function. So essentially everything you need to run such a software download business is in one place.

For your nice to have:

- The design can be [customised](http://docs.whmcs.com/Client_Area_Template_Files). But if you want to remove the "Powered By" Linkback, it [cost](https://www.whmcs.com/order/) a little more.
- This is from the "[Product Downloads Distribution](http://docs.whmcs.com/Product_Downloads_Distribution)" function page:

> ... WHMCS will automatically handle the download permissions and only
>   allow the items to be downloaded by customers that purchase the
>   associated required product and only when that product is active in
>   their account

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think any eCommerce solution would suffice.

Personally, I am familiar with CubeCart. Orders can be created in admin, the purchased digital files are "served" by a file manager where permission to download is checked for exceeding download count and for being within a time frame.